# Ubuntu 23.10 Firmware update prevents system booting after failed UEFI revocation database update

Tags: firmware, 23.10

Running Ubuntu 23.10.     ASUS Z170 Pro motherboard

Ubuntu Firmware notifier tell me UEFI dbx (UEFI revocation database) at current version 77 can be updated to latest version 371.

Click update to latest.

Then Failed to install firmware.

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied:  An AppArmor policy prevents the sender from sending this message to this recipient. ...w/details of /snap/firmware-updater/109/bin/firmware-updater
```

Reboot then gives errors

```
Could not create MokListRT: Volume full
Could not create MokListXRT: Volume full
Could not create SbatLevelRT: Volume full
Could not create MokListTrustedRT: Volume full
Something has gone seriously wrong...
```

Reboot can then only be achieved by logging into BIOS and clearing secure boot keys.

The "nag" to update the firmware also keeps popping up.

EDIT: Now blocked firmware updates of the offending device using

```
fwupdmgr get-updates
```

(lists devices with firmware updates with GUIDs)

```
cd /etc/fwupd
```

add GUIDs of devices you want disabled in the updater

```
sudo vi fwupd.conf
```

add new line with parameter for any device(s) you want to disable future checking (as per man 5 fwupd.conf)

```
DisabledDevices=<GUID1>;<GUID2> etc
```

restart the fwupd daemon

```
sudo systemctl restart fwupd
```

check to confirm that updates for offending device no longer offered

```
fwupdmgr get-updates
```